# DataTables "No Data Available in Table" text position change

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have two datatable having id table1 and table2,By default "No Data Available in Table" text is center, i need to change the text of only table2 to left

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do it by css

```
table.dataTable td.dataTables_empty{
  text-align:left;
}
```

here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/a3h58xyo/1/)

Comment: but this cause both table  text to align to left, i only need  table1 to show text to left

Comment: use tableID to do that